# How can I get Google calender events created/updated in last week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, google-api

I am using Ruby API client

See my code:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN
calendar = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
result = client.execute(:api_method => calendar.events.list,
                            :parameters => {'calendarId' => 'primary', 'updatedMin' => 1.week.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%T")

})
```

It seems `updateMin` is not working. I am getting all event items. Anything wrong in my approach? Please guide me to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same code works now. I guess it was some unexpected error at API.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

It appears that the optional parameter might be **timeMin** rather than **updatedMin**.